# Checking the legitimacy of a simple one-way Anova simulation

Tags: r, anova, sampling, simulation, effect-size

## Background:

My question is based on [**This Paper**](http://kujira.psy.senshu-u.ac.jp/~ken/Okada2013bmtrk.pdf) (see its *Appendix* for R code). The paper is trying to basically obtain the empirical distribution of a statistic called $\eta^2$ (eta-squared) via large replications. If we assume a one-way ANOVA with a normal population for each level (i.e., group), the population parameter of this statistic ($\eta^2$) is defined as:

$\eta^2 = \frac{\sigma_{\text{between normal levels' means}}^2}{\sigma_{\text{between normal levels' means}}^2 + ~\sigma_{\text{within each normal level}}^2}$ (see `pop.eta.sq` below)

where $\sigma_{\text{between normal levels' means}}^2$ is the variance between levels means, and $\sigma_{\text{within each normal level}}^2$ is the variance common to all levels (I set this to $1$).

## Question:

Based on "page 137" of [**This Paper**](http://kujira.psy.senshu-u.ac.jp/~ken/Okada2013bmtrk.pdf), as sample size increases the expected value (*the filled black circles in picture below*) of the replications should get closer to the `pop.eta.sq`. **But why I see the opposite in my simulation below in R (see picture below code):** *is my simulation legitimate?*

```
Anova = function(n, means = c(0, .4, .8, 1.2), n.sim = 1e3){
    k = length(means)
 sigb = var(means)*(k-1)/k # "*(k-1)/k" changes sample variance to pop. variance 
pop.eta.sq = round(sigb / (sigb + 1), 3) # I have set Sigma.within.each.normal.level = 1

eta.sim = Vectorize(function(n){
    eta = numeric(n.sim)
for(i in 1:n.sim){ 
     y = as.vector(unlist(mapply(FUN = rnorm, n = rep(n, k), mean = means)))
groups = gl(k, 1, k*n)
   sim = anova(aov(y ~ groups))
eta[i] = sim[, 2][1] / (sim[, 2][1] + sim[, 2][2]) # sample estimate of eta.sq
  }
  hist(eta, main = NA)
  mtext(paste0("Sample Size = ", n, "\n", "Pop.eta^2 = ", pop.eta.sq), font = 2)
  points(mean(eta), 0, pch = 19, xpd = NA, cex = 2)
  text(mean(eta), 0, round(mean(eta), 3), font = 2, pos = 3, xpd = NA)
  }, "n")
  par(mfrow = c(2, length(n)))
  invisible(eta.sim(n))
  }
Anova(n = c(5, 50)) # Two different group sample sizes, 5 & 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an bug in your code; your `group` variable is not correct. Replace that line with this:

```
groups = factor(rep(1:k,each = n))
```

and it should work properly.